# How to fix printing the even and odds when typing the same number

Tags: java

My code is working when i input different amount of numbers, but the issue is when i enter the same amount of number it wont show up in the ODD and EVEN section.

I tried manipulating it on //Getting the odd & even Section, but it ends up with no print output. I use the equation `if (c[i] % 2 != 0)` of getting the odd and `if (c[i] % 2 == 0)` for getting the even.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a[] = new int[100];
        int b[] = new int[100];
        int c[] = new int[100];
        int j, temp;
        int i;

        // Entering Class Size A

        System.out.print("Enter class size: ");
        int firstarraysize = in.nextInt();

        // Input number A

        for (i = 0; i < firstarraysize; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
            a[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        // Sorting Array A

        for (i = 0; i < firstarraysize; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < firstarraysize; j++) {
                if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        // Output A

        i = 0;
        System.out.print("A: ");
        while (i < firstarraysize) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        // Entering Class Size B

        System.out.print("Enter class size: ");
        int secondarraysize = in.nextInt();

        // Input number B

        for (i = 0; i < secondarraysize; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
            b[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        // Sorting Array B

        for (i = 0; i < secondarraysize; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < secondarraysize; j++) {
                if (b[i] > b[j]) {
                    temp = b[i];
                    b[i] = b[j];
                    b[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        // Output B

        i = 0;
        System.out.print("B: ");
        while (i < secondarraysize) {
            System.out.print(b[i] + " ");
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        // Mixing Output A + B

        int totalinputs = firstarraysize + secondarraysize;

        for (i = 0; i < firstarraysize; i++) {
            c[i] = a[i];
        }

        for (i = 0; i < secondarraysize; i++) {
            c[i + firstarraysize] = b[i];
        }

        // Sorting C

        for (i = 0; i < totalinputs; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < totalinputs; j++) {
                if (c[i] > c[j]) {
                    temp = c[i];
                    c[i] = c[j];
                    c[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        // Output C

        i = 0;

        System.out.print("C: ");

        while (i < totalinputs) {
            System.out.print(c[i] + " ");
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        // Getting the ODD numbers of C

        System.out.print("Odd: ");
        for (i = 0; i < c[i]; i++) {
            if (c[i] % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.print("" + c[i] + " ");
            }
        }



        // Getting the EVEN numbers of C

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Even: ");
        for (i = 0; i < c[i]; i++) {
            if (c[i] % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print("" + c[i] + " ");
            }
        }

        // Getting the Sum of the ODD numbers of C

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Odd Sum: ");

        int oddssum = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < totalinputs; i++) {
            if (c[i] % 2 != 0) {
                oddssum = oddssum + c[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.print(oddssum);

        // Getting the SUM of the even numbers of C

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Even Sum: ");

        int evensum = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < totalinputs; i++) {
            if (c[i] % 2 == 0) {
                evensum = evensum + c[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.print(evensum);

        //Getting the Average of Oddssum + evensum
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Average: ");
        double average = oddssum + evensum;
        System.out.print(average/2);

    }
}
```

```
Output:

Enter class size: 3
Enter Number: 2
Enter Number: 3
Enter Number: 1
A: 1 2 3 

Enter class size: 3
Enter Number: 1
Enter Number: 2
Enter Number: 3
B: 1 2 3 

C: 1 1 2 2 3 3 

Odd: 1 
Even: 

Odd Sum: 8
Even Sum: 4
Average: 6.0

==============================================================================
*IF I INPUT DIFFERENT NUMBERS*

Enter class size: 3
Enter Number: 2
Enter Number: 3
Enter Number: 1
A: 1 2 3 

Enter class size: 3
Enter Number: 8
Enter Number: 5
Enter Number: 6
B: 5 6 8 

C: 1 2 3 5 6 8 

Odd: 1 3 5 
Even: 2 6 8 

Odd Sum: 9
Even Sum: 16
Average: 12.5
```

Comment: You mean something like System.out.println((num % 2) == 0 ? "EVEN " + num : "ODD " + num)?

Comment: @user12012567 sorry but I realy do not understand your question. Please tell us 
What is your Input your output and expected output in a simple way.

Comment: Fascinating code! The problem is not with same numbers. The problem is with both classes starting with 1. When finding your even and odd numbers, you should be iterating till 'totalinputs', not till c[i].

Comment: the output was there below the code. When i input 123123 it wont find the even and odd number. when i input 231856 then it works fine. i have issues with entering same amount of number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When printing your even and odd numbers, you loop unil `c[i]` which is 1 when entering your provided input. Instead you should use the total quantity of numbers as limit:

```
  for (i = 0; i < totalinputs; i++) {
        if (c[i] % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.print("" + c[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

You have to do the same for your even numbers.

Comment: you can also used this statement like : if (c[i] & 1 == 0){ }

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Odd and even numbers are the for-Loops:

```java
for (i = 0; i < c[i]; i++) {
    if (c[i] % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print("" + c[i] + " ");
    }
```

You want to iterate trough `c` to find the odd and even numbers but what you actual doing is limiting the for loop ever round because you use `c[i]` as border which is `1` in first round and so stops immediately.

Try this loop:

```java
int[] a = {1,2,3};
for(int i : a){
  if(i%2 != 0){
     //odd
  } else {
     //even
  }
```